# Is there any way to make this python code simpler?

Tags: python

```
if pop0_dict['max_value1_index'] in (4,5) or pop0_dict['max_value2_index'] in (4,5) or \
    pop1_dict['max_value1_index'] in (4,5) or pop1_dict['max_value2_index'] in (4,5) or \
    pop2_dict['max_value1_index'] in (4,5) or pop2_dict['max_value2_index'] in (4,5) or \
    pop3_dict['max_value1_index'] in (4,5) or pop3_dict['max_value2_index'] in (4,5) or \
    pop4_dict['max_value1_index'] in (4,5) or pop4_dict['max_value2_index'] in (4,5) or \
    pop5_dict['max_value1_index'] in (4,5) or pop5_dict['max_value2_index'] in (4,5):
```

It seems very much repeated, so I was wondering if there's any way to make it simpler, albeit still readable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `any`:

```
dicts = [pop0_dict, pop1_dict, pop2_dict, pop3_dict, pop4_dict, pop5_dict]
indices = ['max_value1_index', 'max_value2_index']
if any(d[i] in (4,5) for d in dicts for i in indices):
    ...
```

The argument to `any` is a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), which lazily produces values as the consumer (`any`) asks for them. As soon as `any` finds a `True` value, it returns `True`, allowing you to avoid performing additional unnecessary containment checks.

Comment: what's the name of this syntax style where you put the for after the condition? I want to read about it.

Comment: It's list comprehension.

Comment: There's no list comprehension here. `d[i] for d in dicts for i in indices` is a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions). The distinction is important: a list comprehension would build a list of all the Boolean values before `any` started to look at it, while the generator expression only produces values for as long as `any` asks for them. If the very first value of `d[i] in (4,5)` is `True`, the rest of the containment checks can be skipped.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, but you better make a list with dictionaries, instead of having separate variables `pop0_dict, pop1_dict, pop2_dict, pop3_dict, pop4_dict, pop5_dict`:

```
if any(d[k] in (4,5) for d in [pop0_dict, pop1_dict, pop2_dict, pop3_dict, pop4_dict, pop5_dict] for k in ['max_value1_index', 'max_value2_index']):
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list_of_dicts = [pop0_dict, pop1_dict, pop2_dict, pop3_dict, pop4_dict, pop5_dict]

for dict_inst in list_of_dicts:
    if dict_inst['max_value1_index'] in (4,5) or dict_inst['max_value2_index'] in (4,5):
        # do something
```

and if you need to add more dictionaries, you can just write a function to populate `list_of_dicts`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution without looping/comprehension syntax:

```py
from itertools import product


if any(
  map(
    lambda d,k: d[k] in (4,5),
    product(
      (pop0_dict, …, popN_dict),
      ("max_value0_index", …, "max_valueN_index")
    )
  )
):
  …
```

Just have to tune the dictionary and key tuples in the product function to suit your actual needs.